# Ad hoc wifi connection lost if no internet activity

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, ad-hoc-network

I have the following setup:

```
DSL-Modem---(ethernet)---Notebook-A---(wireless)---Notebook-B
```

The wireless connection is an adhoc network. In Notebook-A I've configured the ethernet adapter to share the Internet connection with the wireless adapter. Both computers are running Windows 7.

I can access Internet from Notebook-B without any problem. BUT: if there is no Internet activity for just a few seconds in Notebook-B, then the adhoc wireless connection is lost and the connection is not shown as an available wireless connection anymore. I have to go back to Notebook-A disconnect the adhoc wireless connections (that is in "waiting for other connections" status) and connect it again, only then I can go back to Notebook-B and connect to the wireless adhoc connection to access Internet.

I know the problem is in Notebook-B, because if I change Notebook-B for other notebook I don't have the problem.

Notes:

- Notebook-A is pluged-in to A/C, never goes to sleep/hibernate mode and never shuts down the wireless adapter.
- Notebbok-B is pluged-in to A/C, never goes to sleep/hibernate mode and never shuts down the wireless adapter (I'm using the computer when this happens).
- DSL-modem is an ubee modem provided by comcast

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough one. Have you considered looking for more up-to-date drivers on Notebook B?
Maybe it has a buggy driver which needs updating.